# Appending filenames in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, append, filenames

I'm very new to Ruby and branching out past first scripts asking what my favorite color is and repeating it back to me. I'm doing what I thought was a relatively simple task, moving files and changing the names.

I have a bunch of files in subdirectories that I need to move to a single directory and then append the file names of all of them. Specifically need to keep the original name and add onto the end, IE AAB701.jpg -> AAB701_01.jpg.

I have managed to find the files and move them (probably inefficiently) but I'm having no luck appending to the file name. Google search, stackoverflow, etc, no luck.

This is the code that I have now.

```
require 'find'
require "fileutils"

file_paths = []
Find.find('../../../Downloads') do |path|
  file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\.jpg$/
end

file_paths.each do |filename|
  name = File.basename('filename')
  dest_folder = "../../../Desktop/Testing/"
  FileUtils.cp(filename, dest_folder)
end

file_paths.each do |fullname|
append_txt = '_01'
filename = "*.jpg"
fullname = File.join(filename, append_txt)

end
```

The actual paths are pretty inconsequential, but I'm not familiar enough with File.join or gsub to figure out what is wrong/best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd extract some work into a small method:

```
def new_name(fn, dest = '../../../Desktop/Testing/', append = '_01')
  ext = File.extname(fn)
  File.join( dest, File.basename(fn, ext) + append + ext )
end
```

Then I'd apply a more functional style to your directory traversal and processing:

```
Dir[ '../../../Downloads/**/*.jpg' ].
select { |fn| File.file? fn }.
each   { |fn| FileUtils.cp fn, new_name(fn) }
```

Also, I don't see what the `Find` module buys you over [`Dir#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) and the dir glob let's you filter to jpgs for free.

Comment: Wow, this is so much cleaner. I've run into a problem though, in that it keeps the file extension and then appends to it. I.E. - AAB701.jpg-01.jpg

Comment: @LukePatton sorry, I forgot that [`File::basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename)'s interface is a little funny. It requires a second arg describing the extension to strip.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Actually fixed it myself. Used the file.basename argument to have it exclude the extension.

EDIT: Just saw your addition, sorry. I had put ".jpg" instead of ext, but ext seems like it'll be better for adapting the script.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler answer is for a file:

```
require 'pathname'

new_name =Pathname(orig_fn).sub_ext("01#{Pathname(orig_fn).extname}").to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your call to FileUtils.cp.

```
append_txt = '_01'
file_paths.each do |filename|
  name = File.basename('filename')
  newname = name + append_txt # + File.extension()
  dest_folder = "../../../Desktop/Testing/"
  FileUtils.cp(filename, dest_folder + newname)
end
```

Note that this code is not safe against malicious filenames; you should search the file handling docs for another way to do this.